# Passing data to searchstring parameter not working

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, ado.net, asp.net-core-webapi, c#-6.0

I have issue when passing value as 'Text6=''locations''' to a parameter searchstring in C#.

It gives me error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'and'.

The problem is in the below function when passing value 'Text6=''locations''' to @searchstring it gives an error as shown.

```
{ 
"startdate": "2020-05-03T22:00:00Z", 
"enddate": "2020-05-11T22:00:00Z", 
"searchstring": "'Text6=''MFG'''", 
"reportID": "2028" 
} 

public DataTable GetReportDetailsSearch(string ReportID, string FromDate, string ToDate, string SearchString)
      {

          List<SqlParameter> param = new List<SqlParameter>()
          {
              new SqlParameter("@ReportID", ReportID),
              new SqlParameter("@ReportDateFrom", FromDate),
              new SqlParameter("@ReportDateTo", ToDate),
              new SqlParameter("@SearchString",SearchString),


          };

  DataTable ReportDetailsSearch = SQLDAL.ReturnDataTableByProcedure("sp_ReportDetailsGetALL", param);
          return ReportDetailsSearch;
      }
```

web API asp.net core 2.2

```
[Route("ReportDetailsSearch")]
       [HttpPost]
       public IActionResult GetSearchedData([FromBody] dynamic DataObjectSearch)
       {

           try
           {
               string ReportId = DataObjectSearch.reportID;
               string FromDate = DataObjectSearch.startdate;
               string StartDate = FromDate.Substring(0, 10);
               string todate = DataObjectSearch.enddate;
               string EndDate = todate.Substring(0, 10);
               string Searchdata = DataObjectSearch.searchstring;

               var PostSearch = _reportservice.GetReportDetailsSearch(ReportId, StartDate, EndDate, Searchdata);

               return Ok(PostSearch);


       }
```

But on SQL Server it works successfully:

```
 exec [dbo].[sp_ReportDetailsGetALL] "2028","2020-05-03","2020-05-11", 'Text6=''locations'''
```

Procedure as below:

```
declare @ColumnName Nvarchar(max) = (SELECT 'select ' + STUFF((SELECT ',' + 'Text'+CONVERT(varchar(20),ReportHeaderIndex) + ' '+ '['+ReportHeader +']' 
FROM ReportHeaders where ReportID=@ReportID order by ReportHeaderIndex 
FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'') + ' , convert(nvarchar(20),[ReportDate]) ReportDate From ReportDetails R where ReportDate >= ''' +@ReportDateFrom+''' and ReportDate <= '''+ @ReportDateTo +''' and R.ReportID =' + @ReportID + ' and '+@SearchString+' and IsHistory=0 order by reportdate desc ' + @SortingColumns AS Txt ) 
exec (@ColumnName)
```

Comment: If the value of  `SearchString` in exactly `'Text6=''MFG'''` then when you put that value into an SqlParameter it is going to escape every single quote for you, therefore passing in `''Text6=''''MFG''''''`. That is one of the advantages of using a SqlParameter, the fact that it escapes data for you.

Comment: thank for reply so what i do to solve issue

Comment: can you please tell me how to write on csharp code

Comment: How i write on csharp code can you tell me please

Comment: `searchstring = "Text6='MFG'"`maybe? You haven't actually show your own C# code.

Comment: what the code you need from me to show you i will post

Comment: I update my post with code you need

Comment: i add quotes from front end because it must have quotes to API executed success

Comment: You don't need to add the *single quotes* for it to be sent as JSON, the double quotes yes, but not the single quotes.

Comment: Send it from your front end as `{ 
"startdate": "2020-05-03T22:00:00Z", 
"enddate": "2020-05-11T22:00:00Z", 
"searchstring": "Text6='MFG'", 
"reportID": "2028" 
} `

Comment: exactly it works thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my issue solved by pass data from front end to web API as below :

```
searchstring = "Text6='MFG'"
```